# Getting inset map selected and magnified in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, pdf, map-book

I want to create a mapbook(PDF) of all states in USA, and also create an inset map by using a second data frame. I got my mapbook to run, but then I can't get the inset map in the second data frame selected and zoomed in.  can i use a "select by attribute" loop? or any other way?

```
# Mapbook

#Imports the operating system module 
import os

#Sets the environment 
import arcpy

#Allows us to re-run the code multiple times, overwriting previous material
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True

#Defines the folder path
folder_path=r"E:\Geog173Programming\Final Project\LabData\tracts (1)"

#Allows to access the arcmap document that I created and saved 
mxd=arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(folder_path+"\Mapbook.mxd")

#Allows it to access the data frame  
df=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Map")[0]

#Creates a final PDF document and titles it
finalPDF_frame=folder_path+"\Mapbook.pdf"
final_PDF=arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalPDF_frame)

#Defines the temporary pdf file 
tmpPDF=folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf'

#Reads that we it will put information in the new empty text box that
#I created 
titlePageinfo=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT")[0]

#Gives the cover page a title, and the authors name
titlePageinfo.text="Population Weighted Centroid of Each State" + "\r" + "By: XXX"

#Assigns it to my temporary pdf
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,folder_path+ r'\tmp.pdf')
#And then appends it to the final pdf
final_PDF.appendPages(folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf')

#Selecting the north arrow,lengend, and scale bar
#and issues a postion of x and y coordinates 
North_Arrow=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT","North Arrow")[0]
North_Arrow=elementPositionX=10.1713
North_Arrow=elementPositionY=7.8034

Legend=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"LEGEND_ELEMENT","Legend")[0]
Legend=elementPositionX=0.5284
Legend=elementPostitionY=0.5784

Scale=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT","Alternating Scale Bar")[0]
Scale=elementPositionX=7.3671
Scale=elementPositionY=0.5532

#Labels the state
lyrlist=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"State",df)
for lyr in lyrlist:
    if lyr.name=="State":
        lyr.showLabels=True

#Defines variable. Searches in the states shp.
inputRows=arcpy.SearchCursor(folder_path+'/states.shp')

#Defines the tile variable. Reads the same text box that
#created earlier 
titleinfo=arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd,"TEXT_ELEMENT")[0]

df2=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Inset")[1]

df2.elementPositionX=8.6642
df2.elementPositionY=0.4446
df2.elementHeight=2.0162
df2.elementWidth=2.8323

#lyrlist2=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"states",df2)
#for lyr in lyrlist2:
    #field="STATE_NAME"
    #cursor=arcpy.SearchCursor(folder_path+'/states.shp')
    #row=cursor.next()
    #while row:
        #feature2=(row.getValue(field))
        #arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("states","NEW_SELECTION","STATE_NAME='Montana'")
        #row=cursor.next()
        #print feature2

#Searches through each row in the state shp.Prints the state name and state FIPS
#for each page
for row in inputRows:
    titleinfo.text="State Name:"+str(row.STATE_NAME)+"\n"+"State FIPS:"+\
                    str(row.STATE_FIPS)
    #Positions the the title on each page at a particular x and y coordinate
    titleinfo.elementPositionX=9.9883
    titleinfo.elementPositionY=8.2111 
    #Pulling out descripitve information and getting value from the state shp.
    feature=row.getValue(arcpy.Describe(folder_path+"\states.shp").ShapeFieldName)
    #Extent of that particualr feature. Zooms in ot the lake.
    df.extent=feature.extent
    #Finally appends it to the temporary pdf, which then appends to the final pdf
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf')
    final_PDF.appendPages(folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf')

    #for row in inputRows:
        #arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd,folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf')
        #final_PDF.appendPages(folder_path+r'\tmp.pdf')

    #Saves and closed the final PDF document
final_PDF.saveAndClose()

print "Done"
```

Comment: What is your inset map of? Extra detail or full extent, or something else?

Comment: For each individual page of the mapbook, i want the state to be selected in the inset map showing the full extent of the US.

Comment: Do you have more than one dataframe called "Inset"?  If not then I'd expect the ListDataFrames line to be `df2=arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"Inset")[0]` - the [0] means the first returned result, and as you've limited it to dataframes called "Inset", then that dataframe should be first one returned.

Comment: Insert map supports page definition query. It,'s enough to have 2 layers in reference map with one of them match, second no match to main dataframe ddp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your code slightly to make it find the matching state in your Inset map and select it.

I changed the `arcpy.SearchCursor` to be an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`, and added another to get a dictionary of all states in the Inset for the Inset selection.  As it loops through the different states, it finds them in the Inset layer and selects them using `setSelectionSet()`.

```
# Imports 
import os, arcpy

# Allows us to re-run the code multiple times, overwriting previous material
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Defines the folder path
folder_path = r"E:\Geog173Programming\Final Project\LabData\tracts (1)"

# Allows to access the arcmap document that I created and saved 
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(folder_path, r"USAMapbook.mxd"))

# Allows it to access the data frame  
mapDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Map")[0] # Main map data frame
insetDF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Inset")[0] # Inset data frame

# Creates a final PDF document and titles it
finalPDF_frame = os.path.join(folder_path, r'Mapbook.pdf')
final_PDF = arcpy.mapping.PDFDocumentCreate(finalPDF_frame)

# Defines the temporary pdf file 
tmpPDF = os.path.join(folder_path, r'tmp.pdf')

# Reads that we it will put information in the new empty text box that
# I created 
titlePageinfo = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")[0]

# Gives the cover page a title, and the authors name
titlePageinfo.text = r"Population Weighted Centroid of Each State" + "\r" + "By: XXX"

# Assigns it to my temporary pdf
arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tmpPDF)
# And then appends it to the final pdf
final_PDF.appendPages(tmpPDF)

# Selecting the north arrow, lengend, and scale bar
# and issues a postion of x and y coordinates 
North_Arrow = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "North Arrow")[0]
North_Arrow = elementPositionX = 10.1713
North_Arrow = elementPositionY = 7.8034

Legend = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "LEGEND_ELEMENT", "Legend")[0]
Legend = elementPositionX = 0.5284
Legend = elementPostitionY = 0.5784

Scale = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "MAPSURROUND_ELEMENT", "Alternating Scale Bar")[0]
Scale = elementPositionX = 7.3671
Scale = elementPositionY = 0.5532

# Labels the state
mapStateLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "State", mapDF)[0]
mapStateLyr.showLabels = True

# Defines the tile variable. Reads the same text box that
# created earlier 
titleinfo = arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT")[0]

# Places the Inset map frame
insetDF.elementPositionX = 8.6642
insetDF.elementPositionY = 0.4446
insetDF.elementHeight = 2.0162
insetDF.elementWidth = 2.8323

stateFields = ['OID@', 'STATE_NAME', 'STATE_FIPS', 'SHAPE@']

# Get details for all the states in the Inset map to
# allow selection in Inset
insetStateLyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "State2", insetDF)[0]
insetStateDict = dict()
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(insetStateLyr, stateFields) as insetLyrCursor:
    for insetRow in insetLyrCursor:
        insetStateDict[insetRow[1]] = insetRow[0]

# Searches through each row in the state layer. 
# Prints the state name and state FIPS for each page
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mapStateLyr, stateFields) as mapLyrCursor:
    for mapRow in mapLyrCursor:
        print "State: {}".format(mapRow[1])
        titleinfo.text = "State Name:" + str(mapRow[1]) + "\n" + "State FIPS:" + str(mapRow[2])
        # Positions the the title on each page at a particular x and y coordinate
        titleinfo.elementPositionX = 9.9883
        titleinfo.elementPositionY = 8.2111 
        # Pulling out descripitve information and getting value from the state shp.
        feature = mapRow[3]
        # Extent of that particualr feature. Zooms in ot the lake.
        mapDF.extent = feature.extent

        # Find state in Inset map and Select it
        if mapRow[1] in insetStateDict:
            stateSelection = [insetStateDict[mapRow[1]]] # setSelectionSet requires a List
        insetStateLyr.setSelectionSet("NEW", stateSelection)
        arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

        # Finally appends it to the temporary pdf, which then appends to the final pdf
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, tmpPDF)
        final_PDF.appendPages(tmpPDF)

# Saves and closed the final PDF document
final_PDF.saveAndClose()
arcpy.Delete_management(tmpPDF)

print "Done"
```

In my testing I set the Selection symbol (in the MXD) to be a solid red polygon so it stands out in the Inset - you could make this whatever symbol you require.

Please note that I probably haven't set up my map layout like you have, so the placements, sizes, page units etc. are likely to be different, but here is a screenshot of one output page.

[image]

Comment: @LMY are you posting from 2 different accounts?  It appears this screenshot belongs on the question [Exporting graduated symbology to pdf](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197133/exporting-graduated-symbology-to-pdf) which is posted by M.Reyes.

Comment: We are two different people, but we are working on the same project.